# issues with cellForItemAt indexPath cell downloading data

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UIColelctionView cell that should contain users names located in a firebase database.

First I referenced the custom cell using:

`let f = FriendCell()`

In cellForItemAt indexPath, I define each cell and reference the array from which the data is coming from. Then I reference the individual user the particular cell will get its data from.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: userResultCellId, for: indexPath) as! FriendCell

    let user = users[indexPath.row]

    f.nameLabel.text = user.name
    print(f.nameLabel.text!)

    return cell
}
```

When I run this, the console `print(f.nameLabel.text!)` actually prints the user names correctly, however they don't seem to pass into the cell correctly.

What I believe is happening is each cell is getting set up before the data is downloaded and the namelabel is returning nil because there isn't a value there. But what's weird is that when I print the value it returns the names correctly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the line:

```
let f = FriendCell()
```

Get rid of that. Then in your `cellForItemAt`, you need to set the properties of `cell`, not `f`.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: userResultCellId, for: indexPath) as! FriendCell

    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = user.name

    return cell
}
```